# Complex Harmonic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know whether there is a criterion about verifying 
**a complex harmonic function (real part & imarginary part are both harmonic) on disk is also holomorphic function**. That is, how to measure the gap between them.

On the other hand, we know Dirichlet problem can be solved for harmonic function if
we have boundary condition but for holomorphic function can we get the further comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion is the Cauchy-Riemann equations, succinctly stated as $\partial f/\partial \bar z =0$.

Given any (reasonable, e.g., continuous or integrable) complex-valued function on the boundary of a domain (also reasonable, e.g. with smooth or Lipschitz boundary), we can get a harmonic function with those boundary values. In general it will not be holomorphic. The boundary values of a holomorphic function cannot be prescribed arbitrarily. One can, however, construct a  holomorphic function with given   real part on the boundary: find a real harmonic function with those values, then add its harmonic conjugate times $i$.